# Update the same template without refreshing from different views in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am implementing a geospatial web app where everything is contained within one template in Django. At the moment I want to update a div in the template to display a Plotly graph, which is most easily created with Python and then passed to the template as a template variable. Is there a way I can update the variables returned, and then update the displayed template without refreshing, from a different view which renders the template initially?

Comment: See javascript and ajax to call another view, get back e.g. a Json resonse and update your html in js. There is thousands if tutorials also with django out there

Comment: @Razenstein I've just learned about ajax calls, do you mean I should get the plotly graph as a json response in the javascript?

Comment: I have never used plotly graph - I just wanted to point out one common way of transfering data from a django view back to a ajax call. Json is just one data structure that you can fill with content.

Comment: @Razenstein Ah okay, I know about ajax calls but didn't realise that plotly graphs could be exported as json objects until now when I looked it up, thank you!

Comment: Maybe they even offer a html5/js version an you can define the chart in html/js and just load the data you want to visualize with a ajax call to django/python and update the chart if there is an js-api.